# Is this Patent infringement?

Tags: united-states, patents

I had this question posed to me:

After reading a live patent for a hovering skateboard, Laura is curious to see if the skateboard will actually hover and decides to make it and to test it. Laura records a video where she describes the patent and her intention to prove the skateboard will not hover.  The video shows Laura building the patented skateboard, and showing that the finished skateboard in fact hovers.  Laura posts the video to YouTube.  Her video is viewed by a multitude of people, many of whom then also build these patented hoverboards using her video as instructions and then sell them. Which of the following is true?

a. Laura is guilty of both direct and indirect infringement.

b. Laura is guilty of indirect infringement.

c. Laura is guilty of direct infringement.

d. The viewers who also built the device using the video as instructions are guilty of direct infringement.

EDIT: In the United States of America

My thought process, Laura is directly infringing by "using" the product in a video and the video itself is inducing others to infringe by enabling the viewers as manufactors of the product. But I am not sure.

However, I understand experimenting with a patent is protected use so I am not sure where this would fall. Moreover, would just creating a video meet the standards of inducing infringement? I am not sure.

Comment: Just my opinion, but the legal definitions I found after a few seconds of searching seemed pretty clear cut.  There would be more opportunity for you and others to learn if you could give your own answer and explain how you came to your conclusion.

Comment: "using her video as instructions": is this significant?  Why?  The information necessary to build the device is already public knowledge because it is in the patent records.  Furthermore, it is infringement to sell a device using the patent-protected invention even if you devised it independently, without any knowledge of the patent or of Laura's video.

Comment: I think this question needs a jurisdiction.  In the uk [there would be no infringement if the patent is used for non-commercial, research, anti-terrorism, experimental medicines and related purposes](https://www.mondaq.com/uk/patent/864400/guide-on-patent-infringement-laws-a-global-perspective)

Comment: Where do you read that experimenting with a patent is protected in the US ?

Comment: @User65535 Specifying a jurisdiction would no doubt allow better, more precise, answers. But the policy here on law.SE is that a jurisdiction tag is never required, and a question should not be closed for lack of one. If no jurisdiction ism stated (or even if ne is) an answer my be given for any specified jurisdiction, whch may be useful to others with similar questions in different places. Feel free to write an answer for the UK, if you like.

Comment: Is Alice in the jurisdiction the patent is valid in? This is the crucial question! As in, Alice could manufacture Colt-knockoffs in Spain in 1850 without violating Colt's 1849 patents in the US because those had no reach in Spain then.

Comment: Yes, Alice is in the jurisdiction of the live patent.